# Displacement node doesn't show up on mesh correctly

Tags: displacement

After looking online the past hour, I decided to make a post here. I am having trouble where the displacement in my render view is extremely different than the one in the material view. After looking online for tutorials and such, I always end up with the same problem too. I'm using Blender 2.79. Photos below

Material View
[image]

Render View
[image]

Nodes
[image]

Comment: Use Blender 2.79b instead of 2.79.6.

Answer (score 1):

Material view does not support actual mesh displacement, so you're just seeing your displacement map approximated as a bump map. Unless your displacement has a very small scale, a bump map approximation will be very different from the final displaced mesh.

Comment: I followed this tutorial on youtube and I copied down exactly what they showed, but every time I did it, the displacement did not copy what was shown in the video. The nodes in my image above are me trying to figure out how to make it work, but there is the video
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=h_QUlIqVIpw&t=1s

Answer (score -1):

I find that using displace modifier is a better way than using the node. In this way, you can adjust the strength of the displacement map.